# Infinite scroll in custom json request

Tags: jquery, json, load, scroll

I'm taking a wild guess here; since i have absolutely no idea if what i want is even possible. Take a look at WIP http://www.mathijsdelva.be/2013. Everything works pretty good, except for a few quirks. On a smartphone/tablet though, loading all my shots in one time is very very heavy so i was thinking of adding a load-on-scroll functionality to my website. I have no idea how i should even begin coding this; it's beyond my capabilities.. Current code:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&photoset_id=' + photoset_id + '&per_page=1000' + '&page=1' + '&api_key=' + apiKey + '&user_id=' + userId + '&jsoncallback=?', function (data) {
    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function (i, flickrPhoto) {
        var basePhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + flickrPhoto.server + '/' + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_b.jpg";
        var basePhotoURLMobile = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + flickrPhoto.server + '/' + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_z.jpg";
        var flickrLink = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/" + data.photoset.owner + "/" + flickrPhoto.id + "/";

        var $img = $("<img/>").attr("src", basePhotoURL);
        var $imgMobile = $("<img/>").attr("src", basePhotoURLMobile);
        var $wrap = $("<div class='item'></div>");
        if($(window).width() < 501) {
            $wrap.append($imgMobile);
        } else {
            $wrap.append($img);
        }
        $wrap.append("<a href='" + basePhotoURL + "'.jpg' title='View full size' class='zoom' rel='enroll' />");
        $wrap.append("<a href='" + flickrLink + "' class='flickr' title='View on Flickr' target='_blank' />");
        $wrap.appendTo('#photographs');
    });

    var loaded = 0;
    var totalAmount = $('#photographs .item').length;

    if($(window).width() > 1140) {
        $('#photographs .item').each(function() {
            loaded;
            $(this).imagesLoaded(function($images) {
                loaded++;
                var percentage =  parseInt((loaded / 51) * 100);
                console.log(loaded + ' van de ' + totalAmount);
                $("#bigloader").progressbar({
                      value: percentage
                    });
                if(loaded == 50) {
                    $("#photographs, #loader").fadeIn("fast");
                    $("#bigloader, #preloading").fadeOut("fast");
                    $("#photographs").gridalicious({
                        gutter: 2,
                        animate: true,
                        effect: 'fadeInOnAppear',
                        width: 430
                    });
                } else if (loaded == totalAmount) {
                    $("#loader").fadeOut("fast");       
                };
            }); 
        });
    } else {
        $('#photographs .item').each(function() {
            loaded;
            $(this).imagesLoaded(function($images) {
                loaded++;
                var percentage =  parseInt((loaded / 51) * 100);
                console.log(loaded);
                $("#bigloader").progressbar({
                      value: percentage
                    });
                if(loaded == 50) {
                    $("#photographs, #loader").fadeIn("fast");
                    $("#bigloader, #preloading").fadeOut("fast");
                    $("#photographs").gridalicious({
                        gutter: 2,
                        animate: true,
                        effect: 'fadeInOnAppear',
                        width: 320
                    });
                } else if (loaded == totalAmount) {
                    $("#loader").fadeOut("fast");       
                };
            }); 
        });
    }
});
```

Does anybody have any clue? I'd be forever grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are scrolling vertically, conceptually you can use the scroll event to make batch ajax requests. That api you are using seems to have page params too.

// Edited from comments below

http://api.jquery.com/scroll
http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/scrollTop

```
functionCalledByScroll(requestNumber) { 
    $.get('<url>' + 'per_page=<amount you need>' + '&page=<requestNumber>', 
        function (data) { 
            $(data).each(<your call back above>);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Keep a count of how many requests you make for the page param. Request some amount (50 items) per scroll difference (say 1000px or more). Then load json objects into html the same way you are doing.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/
http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/scrollTop
http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/scrollLeft

$.get('<url>' + 'per_page=1000' + '&page=1', function (data) { $.each(<your call back above) }); 

Keep a count of how many you have loaded

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/
http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/scrollTop
http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/scrollLeft

'functionCalledByScroll(requestNumber)
{
    $.get('<url>' + 'per_page=<amount you need>' + '&page=<requestNumber>', 
   function (data) { $(data).each(<your call back above>) }); 
}'

Keep a count of how many requests you make for the page param. Request some amount (50 items) per scroll difference (say 1000px or more). Then load json objects into html the same way you are doing.

My last comment was crap.

Comment: Add an answer instead of a comment! You can write code there :)